# test update request with RSpec failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have two problems when I try to test the update action with RSpec, here is the `controller` file:

```
#volunteers_controller.rb

module Api
  module V1
    class VolunteersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :find_volunteer, only: %i[show update destroy]

      def update
        @volunteer.update!(volunteer_params)
        head :no_content
      end

      private

      def find_volunteer
        @volunteer = Volunteer.find_by!(id: params[:id])
      end

      def volunteer_params
        params.require(:volunteer).permit(:image_url, :name, :job_desc)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Here is the `test` file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::VolunteersController, type: :request do
   ...

    describe '#update' do
       let(:volunteer) { Volunteer.create!( :image_url=>"first.jpg", :name=>"test1", :job_desc=>"description") }       
       let(:params){
            {:volunteer =>  {
                "image_url"=>"new.jpg", 
                "name"=>"test1", 
                "job_desc"=>"description"
            }
            }
        }

        it 'updates a certain volunteer' do
            patch :patch, :params => params #failed, bad URL
            expect(volunteer.image_url).to eq("new.jpg") #failed, still return 'first.jpg'
        end



        it 'returns a no_content header' do
            patch "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", :params => params
            expect(response).to have_http_status "204"
        end

    end

end

private

   def json_parse(string)
     if string.class==String
       json = JSON.parse(string)
     end
       json
    end
```

So my questions are:

1. when try to write the URL like this: `patch :patch, :params => params`, I got the following error:

```
 Api::V1::VolunteersController#update updates a certain volunteer
     Failure/Error: patch :patch, :params => params

     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80patch"
```

How can I change the URL to: `"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}"`?

2. I manually test the update action, putting a `binding.pry` in the `update` action, it does update `volunteer` subject, however, when it goes back to the test, it shows that it doesn't not get updated, why is that?

Thank you!!

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel that obviously won't work since this is a request spec - not a controller spec.

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is really your update method itself and its complete lack of error handling and meaningful feedback to the client. `update!` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if the input is invalid - which is not rescued at all in your controller. And exceptions should no be used for normal code flow - invalid input is not really an exceptional event.

Instead you should rewrite your controller so that it checks if the update is performed and returns the appropriate response:

```
def update
  if @volunteer.update(volunteer_params)
    head :no_content
  else
    head :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

As for the spec itself you're mixing up controller specs and request specs. While they look somewhat similar  the key difference is that a request spec sends actual HTTP requests your rails server while a controller spec stubs the actual request and passes it to an instance of the controller under test.

In a controller spec you could write:

```
patch :update, params: { ... }
```

Because its actually calling the update method on an instance of the controller. But of course:

```
patch :patch, :params => params #failed, bad URL
```

Will not work in request spec since its not a valid URL and request specs send actual HTTP requests. Note that you should pass relative URLs and not absolute URLs as the test server may run on a different port then the dev server

```
# Bad
patch "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", :params => params

# Good
patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params
```

ActiveRecord models are not "live reloading" - the representation in memory will not automatically be updated when the values in the database are updated. You need to manaully reload the record for that to happen:

```
it 'updates a certain volunteer' do
  patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params
  volunteer.reload
  expect(volunteer.image_url).to eq("new.jpg")
end
```

Altogether your spec should actually look something like:

```
# Describe the endpoint - not the controller implmentation
RSpec.describe "V1 Volunteers API", type: :request do
  describe 'PATCH /api/v1/volunteers/:id' do
    # use do ... end if the expression does not fit on one line
    let(:volunteer) do 
      # enough with the hashrockets already! 
      Volunteer.create!(
        image_url: "first.jpg", 
        name: "test1", 
        job_desc: "description"
      ) 
    end

    context "with invalid parameters" do
      # some set of failing parameters
      let(:params) do
        {
          volunteer:  {
            name: ""
          }
        }
      end

      it "returns unproccessable entity" do
        patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params 
        expect(resonse).to have_http_status :unproccessable_entity
      end

      it "does not update the volunteer" do
        patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params 
        expect { volunteer.reload }.to_not change(volunteer, :name).to("") 
      end
    end

    context "with valid parameters" do
      # some set of failing parameters
      let(:params) do
        {
          volunteer:  {
            image_url: "new.jpg", 
            name: "test1", 
            job_desc: "description"
          }
        }
      end

      it "returns no content" do
        patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params 
        expect(resonse).to have_http_status :no_content
      end

      it "updates the volunteer" do
        patch "/api/v1/volunteers/#{volunteer.id}", params: params 
        expect { volunteer.reload }.to change(volunteer, :image_url)
        .to("new.jpg") 
      end
    end
  end
end
```